# Challenging Analysis for Random occurrence of very highly extreme values in the data

Tags: r

I have the following data set (given below). This data has **very high extreme values** (as shown in the sample data) ***with approximately 8-10 extreme values per day out of 96 daily observations***. I have 4 months of data for this study. I have tried one statistical method to handle this data but un-succeeded. My Question is that ***"In r-Language is there any method OR package which will handle such kind of data efficiently"***. Please suggest if any... Thanks

Date & Time          ---------V1    -------  V2 --------        V3

9/18/2014 11:43 --  528 ------  1086    ------- 25 
9/18/2014 11:58 --  509 ------  1047    ------- 25 
9/18/2014 12:13 --  519 ------  1066    ------- 25 
9/18/2014 12:28 --  528 ------  1086    ------- 25 
9/18/2014 12:43 --  509 ------  1047    ------- 25 
9/18/2014 13:13 --  643 ------  1323    ------- 25 
9/18/2014 13:28 --  528 ------  1086    --- ----25 
9/18/2014 13:43 --  509 ------  1047    ------- 25 
9/18/2014 13:58 --  300984---618997 --- 1135 
9/18/2014 14:13 --  250036---514218 --- 1111 
9/18/2014 14:28 --  252533---1100   --- ---963 
9/18/2014 14:43 --  528 ------  600059  --- 1259 
9/18/2014 14:58 --  274771---565087 --- 2197 
9/18/2014 15:13 --  296807---610407 --- 3036 
9/18/2014 15:28 --  650 ------  810308  --- 2740 
9/18/2014 15:43 --  259148---532899 --- 194792 
9/18/2014 15:58 --  382764---1250   --- ---46106 
9/18/2014 16:13 --  125863---258847 --- 105146 
9/18/2014 16:28 --  528 ------  1086    ------- 25 
9/18/2014 16:43 --  528 ------  1086    ------- 25 
9/18/2014 17:13 --  528 ------  1086    ------- 25 
9/18/2014 17:28 --  643 ------  1323    ------- 25 
9/18/2014 17:43 --  528 ------  1086    ------- 25

Comment: The question you are asking really isn't very clear.

Comment: Dear user 2662639: Actually this data is recorded during an experimental studies and we have found these highly extreme values along with normal range values. We expect the increase in the normal values but not in random fashion. The experiment performed several time but the results are same. So now we have to accept the results and handle the data with statistical tools only.

Comment: Zeeshan, it isn't clear to me what result you want. Without knowing the problem domain, I don't know if those extreme values are measurement errors, or if you want to understand how the extreme values are distributed.  It would be helpful if you could indicate the desired result.

Comment: You can handle extreme values efficiently in many ways, but ONLY with respect to your objective. In some cases it's better to ignore them, substitute them with another value (general mean, minimum extreme value, etc.), treat them as a different group and do an analysis just for those, transform you whole data set in a way that extreme values are penalised, etc. My point is that you haven't clarified what is your objective.

Comment: Dear Derwin Mc Geary and AntoniosK, thanks for your comments. My objective is that I am interested in Statistical Process Control i.e. To develop some quality control chart that monitor the process shift efficiently   but due to high number of extreme values I am unable to detect the shift efficiently. As mentioned by AntoniosK I have already used log-transformation and general mean as a replacement of these extreme values, But both methods NOT give the suitable results. For instance if a value is suddenly changes from 500 to 1500000 then how it will handle?

Comment: Frequency of these extreme values is 8-12 values per day out of 96 daily values.In this case when they occurred randomly in a single day we are unable to deal these separately; It is not possible to make the separate process control chart for these extreme values due to their random pattern. So in this experiment we expect the significant increase in the data but its pattern is like: 500, 1500, 4000,3500, 1300, 700 but not like 500, 1500000, 650, 732, 543, 1700000. Being a statistician I have only the data to make analysis. So any appropriate method which deal the situation please suggest.